# TCP stack validation test tool

Tags: tcp, automated-tests

I am porting a TCP stack to our embedded system.

Is there any validation test tool to ensure that our TCP stack fulfills TCP protocol requirements? such as re-order, re-transmission, congestion control etc.

Validate new TCP stack with off-shelf TCP is a way of testing, and this is what I am doing now. But in this way, every TCP protocol details are not covered: such as duplicated/lost/re-order of some TCP fragments, different TCP options etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest set up two environments, one using your TCP stack and the other using off-shelf TCP stack. Collect the traces in the two environments and compare them with each other.

Look at this papar for inspirations:
[Validation of simulated real world TCP stacks](http://www.wand.net.nz/pubs/218/pdf/wns2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks.Validate our own TCP stack with